# Open downloaded font files in windows store winjs app

Tags: javascript, fonts, windows-store-apps, winjs

In my HTML and JavaScript based Windows 8.1 app I'm downloading custom ttf and otf font files. The files downloads over https and is stored in the appdata/local folder. Once the font is downloaded I create a stylesheet with @font-face declaration to use the font.

The font is references with `ms-appdata:///local/fontfile.ttf`. But, the file can't load due to a "`Can’t load <ms-appdata:///local/fontfile.ttf>. An app can’t load remote web content in the local context.`" error.

If I download an image and add that to the DOM with the same technique everything works. The font files also works on a regular web site, so it's not the file itself either.

Any ideas how I can get downloaded font files to work?

Comment: You might be able to add the Uri to the app manifest as a safe location. Why not just predownload the font and include it as `Content`? Most font licenses that would allow downloading and storing would allow embedding.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I actually tried to add it to a safe location, but that doesn't work either. The reason for me to download them at runtime is that the fonts is created by the user in another app and can't be bundled at compile time.

Comment: Any reason you're trying to download them and not just use them directly in the HTML page?

Comment: You might not be able to add font uri to the local context. refer [restrictions in the local context](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/hh465373.aspx).